# Condense elements in table with Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table, bootstrap-4

Id like to condense the input and have a nowrap on the table column to condense it more.  I am not sure how to approach this best with Boostrap 4.4.1.

```
<td class="text-center">
                    <div class="row"">
                        <div class="col">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input data-bind="value: row.timeIncrements, " id="TimeIncrements" maxlength="3" name="TimeIncrements" placeholder="60" type="text" value="">
                                <div class="input-group-append">
                                    <span class="input-group-text">min</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                                <button type="button" title="More information" class="btn btn-info" data-bind="help: { url: '/directors/dashboard/help?viewName=~%2FAreas%2FDirectors%2FViews%2FEventGridSchedule%2FTimeIncrementsHelp.cshtml&amp;sportId=1', title: 'Time Increments' }"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></button>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe apply `max-width` ?

Comment: Thanks but that doesnt fix the nowrap issue.

Comment: If you want the icon to sit next to the input you'll have to change the display of the `.input-group` from `flex` to `inline-flex` so it doesn't sit on it's own line and width from `100%` to `auto` so it does't take full width, I'm pretty sure you can find some classes for those if not use your own classes.